# Shell_exec return value NULL on shell command

Tags: php, json, bash, shell, sh

i'm trying to get the value of my vg space disk.
When i run the command in my shell i don't have any problem that returns the correct value, but when i include it in a PHP file i have a return of a NULL value.

I have see a lot of threads discuting about it but none of the answers solved my problem :(

What commands works ? This one :

```
$variable = shell_exec("df -h | grep "username" | awk '{print $3}'");
```

I don't think it's a permission problem cause this commands works..
For the test script has 777 and root permission.

The code who has the problem :

```
$test = "VG Size";
$tailletotaleduserveur = shell_exec("vgdisplay vghome | grep ".$test." | awk '{print $3}'");
echo json_encode($tailletotaleduserveur);
```

The actual result in network tab : null   -> http://prntscr.com/nehsmb

It should return "5.85"

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Questions: Which script has mod 777? I don't see a script? What sou you mean with "root permission"? What is the output if `df -h`? Is there line with literal `username`?

Comment: The script which contains the command $tailletotaleduserveur..  The script is owned by root, please read the command who does not works, the df - h is working. You are reading the wrong line. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command fails in a shell as well:

```
bash$ vgdisplay vghome | grep VG Size | awk '{print $3}'
grep: Size: No such file or directory
```

You have to quote `'VG Size'`:

```
$tailletotaleduserveur = shell_exec("vgdisplay vghome | grep '".$test."' | awk '{print $3}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Final answer for my problem :) :

```
$test = 'VG Size';
$tailletotaleduserveur = shell_exec("/usr/bin/sudo vgdisplay vghome | grep '".$test."' | awk '{print $3}'");
```

So that other guy ;) were in part right ;) i will confirm your answer, thanks